# why i can not find anything use space in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, search

for example , my document has a field ,value is 'men in black',I use regex search men or in or black ,system can find record,I use 'men in black' search it no result back,but i use 'men.in.black' search it's ok,why? how to use space to find it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably your regex is not correct. Use `\b` to specify word boundaries and list all words you are searching for:

```
db.test.find({field:{$regex:/\b(man|in|black)\b/}})
```

- "main in black" - OK
- "woman at red"
- "woman in pink" - OK

Answer (score 0):

Space is represented in regex as `\s`.

Dot `.` represents *any symbol*, and it will match spaces too, but that's probably not what you want.

I suppose you should get some tutorial on regex, or at least read [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).